# How to include all function and package declarations in a file called all.lisp for an asdf package-inferred-system

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

So, in the asdf manual/documentation in section 6.5 of the package-inferred-system extension, the example uses an all.lisp file for determining packages (which I/we will assume will contain all of the function and package information for that respective subdirectoty).

What I want to know is what would be the "proper" way of including all of the function and package declarations in this all.lisp file. Would I do something like including all of the function declarations for that subdirectory in the all.lisp file, and then use the register-system-packages function in the asdf file. Or could I omit the all.lisp file, and let the compiler infer the packages from the files (but would I have to then use the register-system-packages function for every single file I add to this system).

I'm just wondering more about the specifics of using this system and the files and declarations that have to be made when adding a new file to the system.

Sorry for the opacity of the question; I can't seem to grasp the specifics of this system

Comment: Did you have a look at http://fare.tunes.org/files/asdf3/asdf3-2014.html? There is a mention of `concatenate-source-op` and bundle operations. Is it what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

1- See how it's done in `lisp-interface-library/*/all.lisp`, using `uiop:define-package` and its `:use-reexport` clause.

See for instance `pure/all.lisp`:

`(uiop:define-package :lil/pure/all
  (:nicknames :pure)
  (:import-from :lil/interface/all)
  (:use :closer-common-lisp)
  (:mix :fare-utils :uiop :alexandria)
  (:use-reexport
   :lil/interface/base
   :lil/interface/eq
   :lil/interface/order
   :lil/interface/group
   :lil/pure/empty
   :lil/pure/collection
   :lil/pure/iterator
   :lil/pure/map
   :lil/pure/set
   :lil/pure/alist
   :lil/pure/tree
   :lil/pure/hash-table
   :lil/pure/fmim
   :lil/pure/encoded-key-map
   :lil/pure/queue
   :lil/pure/iterator-implementation
   :lil/pure/map-implementation
   :lil/pure/set-implementation
   :lil/pure/alist-implementation
   :lil/pure/tree-implementation
   :lil/pure/hash-table-implementation
   :lil/pure/fmim-implementation
   :lil/pure/encoded-key-map-implementation
   :lil/pure/queue-implementation
   ))`

2- These days, I recommend use requiring asdf 3.1 and not using asdf-package-system. For maximal backward incompatibility, use

`#-asdf3.1 (error "<my system> requires ASDF 3.1 or later. Please upgrade your ASDF.")`

And then in your `defsystem`, `:class :package-inferred-system`

3- I do not follow this forum closely. ASDF questions find a quicker answer on the `asdf-devel` mailing-list.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret that, you would simply have the package defined in `all.lisp` depend on the packages defined in the other files of that system.  It is then, in a way, an entry point for the dependency graph into that system.  I would expect `all.lisp` to contain high level entry definitions that naturally depend on the other files.

For example, if you build a system that has a (sub-)system for exposing a web interface, the `webinterface/all.lisp` file/package would contain functions for configuring, starting, and stopping the web server.  These functions would depend on the handler definitions in other files/packages which in turn would depend on other files/packages that provide the data or do the meat of request processing.